# Awesomium got blank page when Form.RightToLeft changed

Tags: winforms, awesomium

I have a Windows Forms Application that uses Awesomium 1.7.4.2 to display webpages.

The problem is that I need to change Form.RightToLeft property at runtime and when I do that my Awesomium WebControl goes blank.

I tried to reload the page, change the url, remove & add the WebControl again, and refresh the control but with no avail.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I found a workaround which is to create a new WebControl after each change on Form.RightToLeft. It doesn't seem great solution but to some degree it works.